# Use wildcards in del command

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory, delete-file

Goal is to delete all jpg and png files in a folder.

```
del "ToDelete/*/*.jpg"
del "ToDelete/*/*.png"

pause
```

This code doesn't delete any of files. Are wildcards used correctly?

Comment: Type `del /?`. `del c:\windows\*.dds c:\windows\*.gr2 /s`

Comment: `del /s "ToDelete\*.gr2" "ToDelete\*.dds"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildcards can only be used in the last element of a path. You can use a `for /D` loop to loop through the parent directories of the files to delete:

```
for /D %%D in ("ToDelete\*") do (    
    del "%%~D\*.jpg" "%%~D\*.png"
)
```

Add the `/Q` switch to delete without prompting.

**Note:** In Windows, use `\` as path separators as `/` might cause trouble.

---

In case you want to delete files in *any* directory depth, use switch `/S` of `del`:

```
del /S "ToDelete\*.jpg" "ToDelete\*.png"
```

Add the `/Q` switch to delete without prompting.